# How to associate package-info with class in Byte-buddy?

Tags: java, jaxb, byte-buddy, package-info

I create package-info of package `foo.bar` and class `foo.bar.BarCl` in next code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        DynamicType.Unloaded<?> make = new ByteBuddy().makePackage("foo.bar").make();
        DynamicType.Loaded<Object> load = new ByteBuddy()
                .subclass(Object.class)
                .name("foo.bar.BarCl")
                .make()
                .include(make)
                .load(Main2.class.getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION);
        load.saveIn(new File("folder"));
        Class<?> loaded = load.getLoaded();
        System.out.println(loaded.getPackage());
    }
```

Class and package info correctly writing in folder:

```
package foo.bar;

interface $$package-info /* Real name is 'package-info' */ {
}


package foo.bar;

public class BarCl {
    public BarCl() {
    }
}
```

But in runtime after injecting this classes i get `loaded.getPackage()==null`
How i can associate package-info with generated class?

P.S. In real task i need to generate package-info with JAXB annotation `@XmlSchema`, that specify xml namespace. Without it, classes have naming collisions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages are class loader respobsibility and not defined by a `package-info` class. You can define them [using the loader DSL](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.7.10/net/bytebuddy/dynamic/loading/ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.html#with-net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.PackageDefinitionStrategy-).

Comment: Thanks, i use `load(Main2.class.getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION.with(PackageDefinitionStrategy.Trivial.INSTANCE));` and this solve the problem!

Comment: @rafael-winterhalter, I am having a similar problem, but I am getting a `Illegal type name` when I hit `make` for a class with an as-yet-unknown package. I am not even getting to the load where I can use this technique. I get the same error if I call `.makePackage(newPkgName).make()`

Comment: @rafael-winterhalter, nevermind. I was actually using a reserved word in my package name. Without that it works as expected. (thanks for an amazing tool, btw)